# how to assign different value to dataframe from a list in python

Tags: python, pandas

I want to create a roster using python. there are three possible shift, 7 working days and names of staff to be rotated.
there can only be max of two staff on a shift and each staff can only have one off day during the week which should never fall on saturday or sunday.
After so many try I was able to create the table with the below code but can't randomly have the shift in the order that I want, the random choice is only populating the table with one value from the shift list

```
import numpy as np
import random
import pandas as pd

shift = ['am', 'pm', 'off']
names = ['ola', 'ade', 'bisi']
days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', ' sunday']
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(shift), index=names, columns =days)
```

Comment: Could you write out what your expected output would be for this data? Please [edit[ your post to include this information; do not write such a description in a comment.

Answer (score 0):

Dataframe is working as expected. Although you use random, you've forwarded just one value (as `np.random.choice(shift)` returns just one value) to the frame, and it is populating all cells with that value.

Luckily, choice accepts one more argument named `size` that will return `np.array` of the given size, so with that, your code should look like this:

```py
shift = ['am', 'pm', 'off']
names = ['ola', 'ade', 'bisi']
days = ['monday', 'tuesday', 'wednesday', 'thursday', 'friday', 'saturday', ' sunday']
df = pd.DataFrame(
    np.random.choice(shift, size=(len(names), len(days)),
    index=names,
    columns=days
)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping out, this solve a part of the problem, hope I can play around this and get it the whole thing working.